# Rule of thumb for hyphenation when justifying text?

Tags: hyphenation, typography

I have typeset a text that is justified and thus requires hyphenation to maintain the column width appropriately.

I was wondering if there is a rule of thumb for how words should be hyphenated?

The software I am using (Adobe InDesign) is hyphenating words like so:

'knowl-edge', 'cir-culation' and 'dif-ferent'

However, my client is saying this should be:

'know-ledge', 'circ-ulation' and 'diff-erent'

According to some websites I have found, the hyphenation done by InDesign is correct but I'm trying to understand why so I can explain why if necessary.

Comment: The rules that give rise to these hyphenations: *dif-ferent* — hyphenate between doubled letters; *cir-culation* — the *maximum onset principle*, which says hyphenate as far to the left as possible, consistent with the other rules. And *knowl-edge* — possibly *don't hyphenate after a short vowel in an accented syllable*.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/615072/2085).

Answer (score 2):

Hyphens at line endings in justified text occur at syllable breaks. InDesign automatically makes use of a database of words with their syllable divisions, I believe.
"Use a hyphen to divide words at the end of a line if necessary, and make the break only between syllables."
https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/punctuation/hyphen_use.html

You could show your client the dictionary entry for a relevant word.
For instance:
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/knowledge

There is a break between “l” and “e.” Knowl·​edge. Therefore: knowl-edge.